# eth.getBalance() always returns 0 in testnet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth

I am developing ethereum wallet api.
For now, I want to get the balance for specific address by using `eth.getBalace()`.

I run testnet following

```
alias geth = 'geth --ipcpath /home/tom/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc'
geth console
```

At this time, I can see the `eth.syncing` is `true`.
And I sent 3 ether in http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/.
But I can get balace by using `eth.getBalance()` method.

When I check the http://etherscan.io, there is success status.
And it is also showing in http://myetherwallet.com.

How can I get balance in my local?

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/why-is-my-ether-balance-0-in-geth-even-though-the-sync-is-nearly-complete

Answer (score 1):

The balance is 0 because you’re not connecting to the correct network when starting geth. The `--ipcpath` just tells geth where to store the IPC file when other local processes want to connect to your node. You need to specify the `--testnet` option to connect to Ropsten. It looks like you want to use the coinbase account for checking your balance, so you should also pass in your address with the `--etherbase` option.

```
alias geth = 'geth --ipcpath /home/tom/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc --testnet --etherbase \'YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE\''
```

To confirm you're connecting to the correct network, you should see something like this in your geth output:

> INFO [02-05|11:33:45] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3

(Note - network=3 is Ropsten)

You can get the full list of geth commands [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options).

Once geth starts, you'll also have to wait for your node to sync in order to get your balance.

Comment: tom@ubuntu:~$ alias gat="geth --ipcpath /home/tom/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc --testnet --etherbase '0x30d4396c2c9054eb2609b81759f288ee5c307cd2' --syncmode 'fast' --cache=2048"

tom@ubuntu:~$ gat console

etherbase address was got from first address of eth.accounts
I run geth again such this, but still return 0.
And can't see the correct connection result "network=3"

Comment: Did you wait for the node to sync? It takes a long time (usually several hours).

Comment: I think you didn't understand me correctly.

I am going to get the all balances for all addresses in my wallet in testnet and main network.
How can I do?

Comment: I am having the same issue with my local geth node that is synchronised with ropsten. But so far I have been getting zero for balances.